# C# copy from/to clipboard data (word XML)

Tags: c#

I've written a C# program that copies text from Microsoft Word to the clipboard, by sending the keyboard event CTRL+C.

After the text is inside the clipboard, I use the following function to extract the text from the clipboard to my variable:

```
string text = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html).ToString();
```

The text stored in the variable is in the following format:

```
Version:1.0
StartHTML:0000000105
EndHTML:0000038765
StartFragment:0000038357
EndFragment:0000038725

<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

**{... lots of HTML code with classes etc. etc. etc.. }**

<!--StartFragment--><span style='font-size:11.0pt;line-height:107%;
font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;mso-fareast-font-family:
Calibri;mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
mso-bidi-font-family:Arial;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;mso-ansi-language:
EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:HE'>Hello sir</span><!--EndFragment-->
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to edit the part where it says "Hello sir", and return the text to Word.

I'm using the next code:

```
text = text.Replace("Hello sir", "Bye sir");
```

**However, I can't find a solution how to replace the text in the clipboard.**

After I replace the text in the clipboard, my next step is to perform CTRL+V in Word and replace the original text.

Comment: `Clipboard.SetData()`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setdata(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

After you call `GetData` to get the data out of the clipboard, you can call [`SetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.setdata(v=vs.110).aspx) to put your updated data back in.

Comment: The problem is that word is not rendering the HTML inside Word. when I press CTRL+V it past the HTML code as it appear on the variable

Comment: @Shai - what format are you using to save it back? You might need to use a different one.

Comment: When I do CTRL+C on Word (office), it save to the clipboard some XML format (becuase word contain also formatting such bold, text color etc) as you can see here: http://pastebin.com/3wQiSBwQ, now I would like to modify the text inside this XML and inject it back to the clipboard

Comment: @Shai, so are you calling `SetData` or not? Can you update your question to include that code too, since that's obviously required even if you're still trying to figure out how to get the correct results from Ctrl+V.

Comment: Can't view pastebin.com from work, can you copy the relevant information into the question?